# Wia Dot One - PIR Events are not created?

Tags: wifi

Recently I have been building some projects using the Wia Dot One and the PIR module which I got with it. I am still new to electronics so I am using the "Blocks" feature on the Wia.io platform.

Currently I am trying to receive events on the [Wia](https://www.wia.io) platform whenever motion is detected by the device. The code seems to upload fine, I know because the Dot One behaves as it did during previous successful deployments. However the events do not appear on the platform. I am working with the blocks arranged as shown below:

[image]

Is there anything I might be missing to get this to work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read over your blocks, it seems to me that you have not included the "Connect to Wifi" block at the start of the block sequence. I included it in my own example and it worked perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Adam! I knew it was something small, somehow I forgot to leave it out for this project.